# how to make some fields only accessible by some type of Users in Django?

Tags: django

**my model.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  
    is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)
    is_creator = models.BooleanField('content creator status', default=False)
    is_mentor = models.BooleanField('mentor status', default=False)
```

Here I am adding three additional fields like is_creator for superuser, is_mentor for a class mentor and is_student for a student, i want to know how to give a new user their role among from above three during signup, so that it can be checked while giving permissions

Comment: Why not use Django's group and permission system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this standard format for roles, and i think its self explanatory about how you will check which user is what

```
ROLES = (
    (1, 'student'),
    (2, 'creator'),
    (3, 'mentor')
)

class User(AbstractUser):
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLES, default=1)
```